# Assert same condition on all elements of a collection

Tags: java, unit-testing, assertj

I'm working with AssertJ and I need to check that all objects in a list have `intField > 0`. Something like this:

```
assertThat(myObjectList).extracting(p -> p.getIntField()).isGreaterThan(0);
```

What's the correct way to achieve this? Should I use some other library?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Option 1**:

Use [`allMatch(Predicate)`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.25.3/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#allMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)):

```java
assertThat(asList(0, 1, 2, 3))
    .allMatch(i -> i > 0);
```

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting all elements of:
  [0, 1, 2, 3]
to match given predicate but this element did not:
  0
```

---

**Option 2** (as suggested by [Jens Schauder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66686/jens-schauder)):

Use `Consumer<E>`-based assertions with [`allSatisfy`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.25.3/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#allSatisfy(java.util.function.Consumer)):

```java
assertThat(asList(0, 1, 2, 3))
        .allSatisfy(i ->
                assertThat(i).isGreaterThan(0));
```

The second option may result in more **informative** failure messages.

In this particular case the message highlights that some elements are expected to be *greater than* `0`

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting all elements of:
  [0, 1, 2, 3]
to satisfy given requirements, but these elements did not:

0
error: 
Expecting actual:
  0
to be greater than:
  0
```

Comment: I didn't know `allMatch` method. That's exacly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: One may also use `allSatisfy` which allows to write a consumer containing assertions. This is a little more code but also more flexible and potentially results in better failure messages.

Comment: @JensSchauder thank you, added it as the second option to the answer

Comment: Incidentally, per the [`allMatch`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.25.3/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#allMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) Javadocs, it looks like these `are` and `have` can be used to the same effect: `assertThat(asList(0, 1, 2, 3)).are(new Condition<>(i -> i > 0, "greater than 0"))` & `assertThat(asList(0, 1, 2, 3)).have(new Condition<>(i -> i > 0, "a value greater than 0"))`.